# Different value when processing POST request in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I have a following situation which I have never seen before. I am using code below to declare a Post action.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Insert(InsertRequest request)
{
     var body = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Now, when I am sending request to this endpoint using Postman with Content-Type =  Application/Json I get some value for request and empty string for body.

If I do PostAsJsonAsync with HttpClient to this endpoint I will get null for request and request content for body.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support `POST` you need to add attribute `[FromBody]` to the request parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Insert([FromBody] InsertRequest request)
{
    var body = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Actually I had [FromBody] before I tried without it, and the results are the same. So that didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you request POST in postman? It may also happen, your request format is invalid and asp.net mvc cannot translate one to another

Comment: 100% sure. If the format is the problem why is it that Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() is different between request made by Postman and PostAsJsonAsync()?

Comment: I have made InsertRequest class as plain as possible and calling this action from PostAsJsonAsync always passes null value as parameter. That is a major problem for me

Comment: Can you post code related with HttpClient and PostAsJsonAsync?

Comment: So, what i now did is replaced PostAsJsonAsync(url, obj)  with client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(jsonObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")); and it worked without any problems. I dont get it